# Should one pronounce “periodic” the same in “periodic acid” and “periodic table”?

Tags: terminology

In “periodic table”, the adjective is related to the noun *period*, and [comes from](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=periodic&allowed_in_frame=0) Ancient Greek *περίοδος* through French *périodique*. In “periodic acid”, it is formed from the prefix *per-* and *iodic* (like *peroxide* and *permanganate*).

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/periodic#Etymology_1) lists their respective UK pronunciations of as `/pɪə(ɹ).iˈɒdɪk/` and `/ˌpɜːraɪˈɒdɪk/`, markedly different: `pɪə` (as in *piece*) vs. `pɜː` (as in *perfume*); then `i` (as in *it*) vs. `aɪ` (as in *eye*).

However, is that distinction really made in practice? Would a native US/UK/Aussie speaker make the difference when talking in the lab?

Comment: It only just occured to me that those words are written the same :)

Comment: I actually call periodic acid period acid just for fun ;D

Comment: Do you "read" books?  I have "read" a few.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am an Australian English speaker and yes, this distinction is made in practice.

Possibly the only reasonable opportunity to use the `pɪə` pronunciation in the name of a compound is in the case of the entertaining molecule *periodane*, which is actually named after the periodic table. This [molecule](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/qua.20948/abstract) (and [later](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/qua.21322/abstract) a number of different plausible isomers) was identified computationally by a methodology called 'mindless chemistry' which optimises randomly generated molecular graphs. *Periodane* is a stable configuration of each atom on the second row of the periodic table, with the exception of neon (although some people are [working](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166128008007677) on that).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not a professional chemist, just a student, but here are some observations from which I can speculate:

Note-- in this post,

`/ˌpɜːraɪˈɒdɪk/`==`per-iodic`

`/pɪə(ɹ).iˈɒdɪk/`==`peer-iodic`

(since IPA is annoying to read)

Remember, it's written as "per-iodic" acid many times. Which means it must be pronounced as "per-iodic" by whoever who reads/writes those texts. So we have *some* evidence showing the use of "per-iodic" as a pronunciation. I don't see any such evidence for "peer-iodic", though one of my teachers used it. I myself initially used "peer-iodic", but once I realized what the acid actually was, I switched to "per-iodic".

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to be pronounced as per-iodic acid schiff but there are many people who dont know that it contains iodine and call it peeriodic acid.